# Wait for jQuery DataTable loaded with Selenium

Tags: jquery, selenium, datatables, wait

I would like to know if there is a way with XPath or CssSelectors, if there is a consistent way to wait until a **[jQuery DataTable](https://www.datatables.net/)** has finished loading for use with **Selenium**.

Comment: no need since all jQuery DataTables share the same skeleton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://datatables.net/reference/event/processing.

> This event is fired when DataTables is doing some kind of processing -
>   be it, sorting, filtering or any other kind of data processing

```
  public static void WaitUntilDataTableHasFinishedLoading(this IWebDriver driver, IWebElement processingTable)
    {
        processingTable.WaitForAttribute("style", "display: none;");
    }
```

Usage:

```
       IWebElement x = SeleniumInfo.Driver.FindElement(By.Id("tableName_processing"));
SeleniumInfo.Driver.WaitUntilDataTableHasFinishedLoading(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

DataTables provides an [initComplete function](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete):

> ...to know when your table has fully been initialised, data loaded and drawn

You can combine it with the Selenium wait()->until() method. Here's an example using php:

```
$this->webDriver->wait($timeoutInSeconds, $intervalInMilliseconds)->until(
        // a php anonymous function executed every $intervallInMilliseconds
        // it tells Selenium to execute some JS in the brower
        // when this methods returns true, Selenium stops waiting
        function(){
            return 'loaded' === func_get_arg(0)->executeScript(
                // the javascript method provided by DataTable
                "$('#dataTableId').dataTable( {
                    \"initComplete\": function( settings, json ) {
                        return 'loaded';
                    }
                }
            );");
        },
        "DataTable still not loaded after $timeoutInSeconds."
 );
```

When the DataTable is loaded, the js $('#dataTableId').dataTable() returns 'loaded' and the php anonymous function returns true and Selenium stops waiting. If the DataTable is not loaded after $timeoutInSeconds seconds, an exception will be thrown with the "DataTable still not loaded after $timeoutInSeconds." message.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to check if I can get this working somehow in C#

Answer (score 0):

in java you can do like this

```
    //Wait for JQuery Load
    public static void waitForJQueryLoad() {
        //Wait for jQuery to load
        ExpectedCondition<Boolean> jQueryLoad = driver -> ((Long) ((JavascriptExecutor) jsWaitDriver)
                .executeScript("return jQuery.active") == 0);

        //Get JQuery is Ready
        boolean jqueryReady = (Boolean) jsExec.executeScript("return jQuery.active==0");

        //Wait JQuery until it is Ready!
        if(!jqueryReady) {
            System.out.println("JQuery is NOT Ready!");
            //Wait for jQuery to load
            jsWait.until(jQueryLoad);
        } else {
            System.out.println("JQuery is Ready!");
        }
    }
```